# I have a php header for my site, with a css animation in it, but I don't want to animation to occur on certain pages

Tags: php, css, animation, header

Is there anyway to do this?

So I have index.php, pagetwo.php, etc.  and in each of these pages is a php include for the header:

in that header file in part, is an animation that I don't want to occur on certain pages.  Short of making two copies of the header, one with the animation, and a header2.php without it, is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set a var in your main files which is picked up in the include.

eg
in index.php/pagetwo.php etc:

```
$AnimateOrNot = 'yes';
include_once('header.php');
```

in header.php:

```
if ($AnimateOrNot == 'yes)
  {
    // show animate
  }
```

(This is how I set the meta title and keywords throughout sites I make)

EDIT:
Obviously check if the variables are set first, and anything else you need to do...etc
ie

```
if (isset($AnimateOrNot) && $AnimateOrNot == 'yes)
  {
    // show animate
  }
```

This will mean if for any reason the var is not set there will be no PHP errors. It also means the default action in this case if it's not set or != to "Yes" will be not to show animation. Switch this if you want the default to show in case of missing var data etc. up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable before the include that the included file will check. For example:

**header.php**

```
<?php if (!empty($animation)): ?>
<style>
...
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**animate.php**

```
$animation = TRUE;
include 'header.php';
```

**dont_animate.php**

```
$animation = FALSE;
include 'header.php';
```

Comment: I think I may have explained this wrong, the header is not the actual header for the HTML;   it's the div that I'm putting at the top of each page.  When I used this the FALSE condition caused the whole element to disappear haha.  I think I need to insert the css for the header into the header.php file, and then wrap it in in the 'if' that you used in your header.php example.

Comment: You can also wrap the specific code with an if statement in your included file. For example: `<div style='background:#000000;<?php if(!empty($animation)):?>animatecss...<?php endif; ?>'>...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']!="/path/to/pagetwo.php")
{
     //show animation
}
```